# Switch with multiple statements for same case

Tags: switch-statement, axapta, x++

I would like to use an statement for multiple cases and then an extra statement for a single case.

```
switch (i)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
        statement1;
        break;
   case 1:
       statement2;
       break;
}
```

So for case 1 statement1 and statement2 should be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could delete the second `case 1` in your code and move `statement2` to your first `case 1`. But this only works if the order of the statements is not important (i.e. `statement2` can be executed before `statement1`):

```
switch (i)
{
    case 1:
        statement2;
        //Fall through

    case 2:
        statement1;
        break;

    default:
        pleaseDoNotForgetMe();
}
```

If the order is important, I think you have no choice but give each case its break:

```
switch (i)
{
    case 1:
        statement1;
        statement2;
        break;

    case 2:
        statement1;
        break;

    default:
        pleaseDoNotForgetMe();
}
```

Comment: Or reverse `case 1` and `case 2` and leave out the `break`. Leaving out `break` should be considered bad style unless commented.